# ASP.NET Membership Database in multiple apps - stay logged in on multiple apps at the same time

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am currently using asp.net membership database on multiple apps. I am not looking for single sign on function. My desire is to be able to logged in at the same time on multiple apps.

But currently, when I log into one app, the other one is logged out instantly. I think the apps issues some kind of Token inside the database so when I log into one app, the other one logs out.

How can I get around this thing?

Comment: If it is acceptable to you using the same application id across apps should solve your problem.

Comment: @faester hmm, that's logical. Only downside is that I have never done that before. exactly how can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do your applications share a
  [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)?
- Do they all target the same membership database?
- Do they share one cookie domain?

Here's part of how I implement it

```
<httpCookies domain=".domain.com.ar"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/" loginUrl="~/login" timeout="43200" protection="All" domain=".domain.com.ar" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

And my membership, roleManager, and profile providers all target the same databases.
Do this in every application, of course.

Note: I know, I know. The [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) article is deprecated, but it still has a very valid C# example of how you should generate your `machineKey`.

They should be formatted like so:

```
<machineKey validationKey="128 hexadecimal characters" validation="SHA1"
            decryptionKey="64  hexadecimal characters" decryption="AES" />
```

Comment: here are the answers : **Do your applications share a machineKey?** yes, but I believe they are not the same. | **Do they all target the same membership database?** certainly yes. | **Do they share one cookie domain?** some of them on the same domain level and some of them others. here is an three example url *www.example.com, sale.example.com, www.example1.com*

Comment: If they are not the same, they aren't sharing one, they all just happen to have one. On the cookies end: you should try having at least `example.com` and `sale.example.com` use the `.example.com` domain. I'm not sure how it'd behave on `example1.com`, but you could give it a shot.

Comment: you are right but the apps are sort of old and it is really hard for me to move them all instantly. so, I shouldn't add `<httpCookies domain=".domain.com.ar"/>` thing then, should I?

Comment: Why not? I didn't mean you should *move* anything, that tag is supposed to set a cookie domain in common for all your applications.

Comment: that's weird. the app who sits on **example.com** can use the cookies of **example1.com**?

Comment: I'm not sure on that count, you could try.. I meant on `example.com`